# Error only occurs in downloaded iOS app store binary

Tags: objective-c, ios

Version 1.2 of my app tested fine on 4, 4S, 5 and in the simulator [on IOS5 and 6] but the version 1.2 that has passed review and has today been released to the app store throws an exception and dies between two of the screens. All the features of v1.2 I expected are present

I've had to put a future date in iTunesConnect to prevent users from updating and I'm hoping users haven't updated already.

The archive is showing as submitted in Organizer with a creation date matching that in iTunesConnect.

Firstly, I'm 99.9% certain that the archive uploaded correctly and is the one in the store. How can I test to be 100%?

Secondly, what do I do next? Contact Apple?

Thanks in advance for the any help on this - severely doubting my sanity right now.
Steve

Here's the exception from the app store download:

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x34ccf29e <redacted> + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x344a197a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreData                        0x339bf8d8 <redacted> + 100
3   CircuitMatePro                  0x000f7d24 - [CircuitPlayerViewControllerfetchSpecificCircuitSetForEditing:] (CircuitPlayerViewController.m:869)
```

18th October 2012 update - I simplified the code in the CircuitPlayerViewC...etForEditing method and resubmitted requesting an expedited review which was granted. After submission the the app review team turned it around within 24hours. It now works as it should in the download. Thanks to all for the help. Steve

Comment: Is this on your development devices? What if you delete the app completely, or try on a different device (one you did not use for beta test or development)?

Comment: Delete the app completely, reinstall from app store - bug still occurs. Completely reset a device, reinstall from app store - bug still occurs. Add provisioning profile to device and run from XCode - bug doesn't occur

Comment: What exception is thrown, and from where?

Comment: Build the app in Xcode using a Distribution scheme (Product->Manage Schemes). Might cause the error to occur while testing locally

Comment: editing the original question with the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is find the cause of the crash. Since Apple approved it for the AppStore, that means this exception didn't happen when they were testing it. You should know best how to find the problem. Crash logs will help you (XCode->Organizer->Devices)

After you fix the problem, request for an expedited review so you can push the update to your users as early as possible:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/index.html

In the "Request Type" field, choose "Critical Bug Fix".

Goodluck!

Update:

Your crash log shows something happening in `[CircuitPlayerViewControllerfetchSpecificCircuitSetForEditing:] (CircuitPlayerViewController.m:869)` with the next function being somewhere inside Core Data. Have you investigated around that area?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can see the crash report but as the bug only occurs on the app store download I have nothing to test.

Comment: You might have already checked, but the crash log seem to point where it was happening. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I've never had to look at crash logs for installed apps before. Made some changes to the method and submitted a request for [and received] an expedited review from the app review team. Thanks again, Steve

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do a check since apple re-sign app with their own code sign , so you can't even do a md5 type checkin. If the date matching between organizer and ituneConnect, you should assume it's the same. By the way IOS5 and IOS6 are totally different. And lot of bugs appear in IOS6 not in IOS5. You have mentioned you make test with different device, but did you check IOS too?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, my tests were on iOS6 on all devices.